# MyBatis, UPPER in a where condition

Tags: mybatis

I have to do a select query with a lot of parameters in MyBatis, I want to use the default mapper xml file structure and add an "UPPER(column_name) = ?" to the result converted query. How Can I do ?

Here is my where clause

```
<sql id="My_Select">
    <where>
        <foreach collection="oredCriteria" item="criteria" separator="or">
            <if test="criteria.valid">
                <trim prefix="(" prefixOverrides="and" suffix=")">
                    <foreach collection="criteria.criteria" item="criterion">
                        <choose>
                            <when test="criterion.noValue">
                                and ${criterion.condition}
                            </when>
                            <when test="criterion.singleValue">
                                and UPPER(${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value})
                            </when>
                            <when test="criterion.betweenValue">
                                and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value}
                                and
                                #{criterion.secondValue}
                            </when>
                            <when test="criterion.listValue">
                                and ${criterion.condition}
                                <foreach close=")" collection="criterion.value" item="listItem"
                                    open="(" separator=",">
                                    #{listItem}
                                </foreach>
                            </when>
                        </choose>
                    </foreach>
                </trim>
            </if>
        </foreach>
    </where>
</sql>
```

and here is the complete select statement:

```
<select id="mySelect" parameterType="myDataExample"
    resultMap="myResultMap">
    select
    <if test="distinct">
        distinct
    </if>
    <include refid="my_Column_List" />
    from istanza_metadato
    <if test="_parameter != null">
        <include refid="My_Select" />
    </if>
    <if test="orderByClause != null">
        order by ${orderByClause}
    </if>
</select>
```

I always receive error like this one

The error occurred while setting parameters

...

WHERE (  UPPER(id_metadato = ?) and UPPER(valore = ?) )

I feel I'm near to the solution, but I can't find a way. Thanks to all

Comment: You shouldn't `UPPER` a expression, add `upper` function in your criterion.condition.

Comment: could you please explain with an example ?

Comment: `WHERE ( UPPER(id_metadato) = ? and UPPER(valore) = ? )` will work.

Comment: Yes, I know that will work, but that is SQL, and not mybatis mapper.xml language. I also know I can type SQL directly, but I try do avoid that. Is there a way I can add Upper to ${criterion.condition} ??

Comment: What is `criterion`'s structure?

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer you correctly, 
I should obtain something like this query 
select distinct ud from my_table where id_metadato=10 AND upper(valore) = 'EURO' and ud in (39,99,40,401);

Comment: In you mapper.xml, you write `${criterion.condition}`, `#{criterion.value}` and so on, so does `criterion` have some other attributes?

Comment: I want to explain I generated mapper.xml with myBatis Generator, so I don't know exactly how it works under the hood. Now I have a particular necessity I can't resolve with the default generated queries (this UPPER condition) and I'm trying to modify the mapper.xml to customize the query.

Comment: Could I ask why you try to upper the column? And which database do you use?

Comment: of course, I use postgreSQL, and I need to search the upper case to avoid user mispelling. That is a request I can't change

Comment: OK, `postgreSQL` can use `ilike` to avoid case sensitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159743/discussion-between-fjordo-and-forward).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem, specs were changed and now I do not need the upper anymore.
By the way before that I handled that problem changing the mybatis like query language to pure SQL language.